# how to control cell reusable in iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c

i have to print date on lable .The date is coming from database it show proper
But problem is i have to compare database date with current date .If database date is smaller then current date then lable should print string @“Due”,otherwise print date like this:03/05/2012.
this code which i am doing in my custom cell class i writen this code in method which i pass in controller class when i scroll my tableview then value is change where i am wrong please help me

```
- (void) updateContent: (Tasksmodal*) taskobject{
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
        [dateFormat setDateFormat:@"dd/MM/yyyy"];

        NSString* duedate = [dateFormat stringFromDate:taskobject.DueDate];


        NSDate *currentdate;
        currentdate=[NSDate date];
        //NSDateFormatter *dateFormat1 = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
        //[dateFormat1 setDateFormat:@"dd/MM/yyyy"];
        NSString* duedate1 = [dateFormat stringFromDate:currentdate];



  if ([currentdate compare:taskobject.DueDate]!=NSOrderedDescending) {
DateLable.text=@"Due";
DateLable.textColor=[UIColor redColor];
```

}

```
else{
    DateLable.text=duedate;
    DateLable.textColor=[UIColor blackColor];
}


}
```

in my controller class .m
// Customize the appearance of table view cells.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    TasksList * cell =(TasksList*) [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[TasksList alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];

    }
    //[[[cell contentView] subviews] makeObjectsPerformSelector: @selector(removeFromSuperview)]; 
    taskobject=(Tasksmodal*)[self.lstTasks objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];    
    [cell updateContent:taskobject];

return cell;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't compare `NSString` like that. You are not comparing dates. Check out [NSDate](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDate_Class/Reference/Reference.html) documentation. Look for `compare`.

```
    if ([currentdate compare:taskobject.DueDate]!=NSOrderedDescending) {
        DateLable.text=@"Due";
        DateLable.textColor=[UIColor redColor];
    }
    else{
        DateLable.text=duedate;
        DateLable.textColor=[UIColor blackColor];
    }
```

Your code is also leaking the `NSDateFormatter`s. You can use a single `NSDateFormatter` to format 2 dates, no need to allocate a new one.

Comment: If Rocky is using `ARC` then he is not leaking, but yes reusing the dateformatter is a good idea.

Comment: ssteinberg but my cell is reusing when i scroll my tablecell then value is change as due and due as 03/05/2012 why this is happen

Comment: Your cell management is probably wrong, post the rest of the method.

Comment: ssteinberg please check my update question i give  what i done

Comment: Make sure 'DateLable' points where you expect. Try reassigning it with 'viewWithTag:'.

Answer (score 0):

You comparison `(duedate<=duedate1)` is checking if the memory address of `duedate` is less than the memory address of `duedate1` because they are both pointer types. This is probably not what you really want :-) . Try something like this instead:

```
if ([taskobject.DueDate timeIntervalSinceNow] <= 0) {
    ... due
}
else {
    ... not due
}
```

Answer (score 0):

NSComparisonResult result = [taskobject.DueDate compare:[NSDate date]];

```
if(result>0)
    DateLable.text=@"Due";
else
   DateLable.text=duedate;
```

Answer (score 0):

You directly can compare NSDate Objects, that infact will be a good and fast approach rather than what you are doing.